# Prestashop Property Combination->quantity is not valid when trying to update combination

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Hi I'm trying to update a combination price but always when I save I get the following error:

**Prestashop Property Combination->quantity is not valid**

Does anyone know how to fix it? I use Prestashop 1.6.1.12

Kind Regards. JDM.

Comment: This occours with all products, also i tried to generate new combinations but still it happens.

Comment: Prestashop updated to last version and still happens

Answer (score 0):

Solved, i forgot that i changed the column quantity to decimal, in the table ps_product_attribute for some tests, i'd changed again to int and works.